# window object model?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I know that there is something called the DOM in javascript. But why isnt there such a thing as a Window Object Model? Doesn't the DOM-tree look like this?:

```
window <- document <- html <- head //etc
```

Comment: Strictly speaking the window object model exists and in addition to the document (which is the representation of the HTML) it also includes the global Javascript scope. But this is not relevant for rendering the page, only the DOM is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the document object model describes how the document is built, and you are the one defining it.

The 'window' is purely a issue of presentation and has nothing to do with the document itself. You are not defining a window or anything about the window.

Answer (score 1):

`window` object is in fact browser dependent part of presentation tier.

`document` object is built depending on the very content of a file (web page) a browser reads.

Answer (score 0):

Window object is part of the DOM.
I suggest you the following articles:

- [The Document-Object Model](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter12.html), chapter 12 from Eloquent Javascript.
- [The Gecko DOM Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_DOM_Reference) from MDN.
- [W3C DOM Model Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-1590626202) (very technical stuff..).

Comment: Isn't it more like the other way around: The DOM is a part of the window object?